# Count data-values from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, function

I am looking for a way to count data-values from checkboxes. As you can see in the example below, when you choose places from checkboxes, it calculates main values, the result is on green box. I need to get also the total number of Screens, Range and Other. It should appear in the SUMMARY section. Thank you!

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sum')
var select = document.querySelector('#select')
var total3 = document.querySelector('#payment-total')
var total6 = document.querySelector('#payment-total2')
var total12 = document.querySelector('#payment-total3')


var screenwad = 5
var screenkalw = 6
var screenzat = 4
var totalscreen = document.querySelector('#total-screen')



var checkboxesTotal = 0;
var selectTotal = 0;

checkboxes.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxSelect)
})

select.addEventListener('click', onSelectChange)

function onCheckboxSelect(e) {
  var sign = e.target.checked ? 1 : -1
  checkboxesTotal += sign * parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  // get selected value and assign it to the global variable selectTotal
  selectTotal = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  renderTotal()
}

function onSelectChange(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    selectTotal = value
    renderTotal()
  }
}

function renderTotal() {
  //NORMALNA CENA
  total3.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal * selectTotal 
  // 10% TANIEJ
  total6.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-10) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)
  // 20% TANIEJ
  total12.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-20) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)

  //WADOWICE
}
```

```css
/*CENNIK*/
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Europa;
}
.pt_title {
    text-align: center;
    background: #2c4949;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.pt_months {
    color: #fff;
    background: #9B8C70;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
.col-x.month {
    text-align: center;
}
.cennik .pt-container {
    padding: 0 100px;
}
.col-x {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.pt_sub {
    background: #F4F1ED;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #00000029;
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;
}
.pt_sub .col-x {
    color: #352B25;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
/*TABLE*/
.cennik ul li {
    list-style: none!important;
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00000021;
    margin-left: 0!important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.cennik ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pt-place {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.pt-place .month {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2c4949;
}
.pt_table ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.pt-place .month span {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2c4949;
}
.pt_months .month {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
/*CHECKBOX*/
.checkbox.col-x {
    color: #858585;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.checkbox.col-x span:hover {
    color: #354949;
}
.styled-checkbox {
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0;
}
 .styled-checkbox + label {
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 0;
}
.styled-checkbox + label:before {
    content: '';
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: #ffffff00;
    border: 2px solid #858585;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.styled-checkbox:hover + label:before {
    background: #ffffff00;
    border: 4px solid #9B8C70;
}
 .styled-checkbox:focus + label:before {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.styled-checkbox:checked + label:before {
    background: #9B8C70;
}
 .styled-checkbox:disabled + label {
     color: #b8b8b8;
     cursor: auto;
}
 .styled-checkbox:disabled + label:before {
     box-shadow: none;
     background: #ddd;
}
.styled-checkbox:checked + label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 6.5px;
    top: 14px;
    background: #FDF1D1;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 0 #FDF1D1, 4px 0 0 #FDF1D1, 4px -2px 0 #FDF1D1, 4px -4px 0 #FDF1D1, 4px -6px 0 #FDF1D1, 4px -8px 0 #FDF1D1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.pt-place.disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
span.discount {
    color: #FFD383!important;
}
.cennik li.pt-place:hover {
    background: #f4f1ed;
}
.pt_footer {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FDF1D1;
    background: #2c4949;
    padding: 20px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.pt_footer span {
    color: #FDF1D1;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#payment-total,#payment-total2,#payment-total3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
.currency {
    color: #fff!important;
    text-transform: lowercase!important;
    font-size: 20px!important;
    letter-spacing: 0px!important;
}
.col-x.spot span {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.col-x.spot {
    margin-top: 5px;
}




.cennik select {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 16px;
}
.cennik select.round {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff00 50%, gray 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, grey 50%, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(#ddd0 70%, transparent 72%);
    background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 2px), calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px), calc(100% - .5em) .5em;
    background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1.5em 1.5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #2c4949;
}

.cennik select.round:focus {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #354949 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, #354949 50%), radial-gradient(#ff000000 70%, transparent 72%);
    background-position: calc(100% - 15px) 1em, calc(100% - 20px) 1em, calc(100% - .5em) .5em;
    background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1.5em 1.5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: 0;
}
.cennik .checkbox {
    margin-top: 0!important;
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
.cennik_page .wpb_raw_code.wpb_content_element.wpb_raw_html {
    margin-bottom: -10px!important;
}
span.link {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="cennik">
<div class="pt_header">
    <div class="pt_months">
        <div class="pt-container">
        <div class="col-x search" style="color: #0000;">Szukaj</div>
        <div class="col-x month">SCREENS</div>
        <div class="col-x month">RANGE</span></div>
        <div class="col-x month">OTHER</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pt_sub">
        <div class="pt-container">
        <div class="col-x">LOCATIONS:</div>
        <div class="col-x month">Digital Signage</div>
        <div class="col-x month">MONTHLY</div>
        <div class="col-x month">MONTHLY</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pt_table">
<ul>
<li class="pt-place">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="checkbox col-x"><input value="190" data-screen="5" type="checkbox" class="sum styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-1">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-1"><span class="link">PLACE ONE</span></label></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>5</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>10,000</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>250,000</span></div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="pt-place">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="checkbox col-x"><input value="190" data-screen="6" type="checkbox" class="sum styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-2">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-2"><span class="link">PLACE TWO</span></label></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>5</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>10,000</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>250,000</span></div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="pt-place">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="checkbox col-x"><input value="130" data-screen="4" type="checkbox" class="sum styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-3">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-3"><span class="link">PLACE THREE</span></label></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>5</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>10,000</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span>250,000</span></div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="pt-place disabled">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="checkbox col-x"><span class="link">SUMMARY:</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="total-screen">0</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="-">0</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="-">0</span></div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="pt_footer">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="col-x spot">
    <span>Spot: </span>
    <select id="select" name="select" class="round">
        <option value="1" class="sum">5 seconds</option>
        <option value="2" class="sum" selected="selected">10 seconds</option>
        <option value="3" class="sum">15 seconds</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-x month"><span>3 MONTHS</span><hr style="border: none;
    margin: 4px;"><span id="payment-total">0</span> <span class="currency">$</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-x month"><span>6 MONTHS <span style="color:#FFD383">-10%</span></span><hr style="border: none;
    margin: 4px;"><span id="payment-total2">0</span> <span class="currency">$</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-x month"><span>12 MONTHS <span style="color:#FFD383">-20%</span></span><hr style="border: none;
    margin: 4px;"><span id="payment-total3">0</span> <span class="currency">$</span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want the global sum (in summary) for just the selected items?

Comment: @Frenchy yes, exactly I need the sum of screens, range and other in the summary from checked Places of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i've added some `id selector` to those fields and created a render function to render the summary section.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sum')
var select = document.querySelector('#select')
var total3 = document.querySelector('#payment-total')
var total6 = document.querySelector('#payment-total2')
var total12 = document.querySelector('#payment-total3')
const totalScreenDiv = document.querySelector('#total-screen');
const totalRangeDiv = document.querySelector('#total-range');
const totalOtherDiv = document.querySelector('#total-other');
const screen1 = document.querySelector('#screen-1');
const screen2 = document.querySelector('#screen-2');
const screen3 = document.querySelector('#screen-3');
const range1 = document.querySelector('#range-1');
const range2 = document.querySelector('#range-2');
const range3 = document.querySelector('#range-3');
const other1 = document.querySelector('#other-1');
const other2 = document.querySelector('#other-2');
const other3 = document.querySelector('#other-3');



var screenwad = 5
var screenkalw = 6
var screenzat = 4
var totalscreen = document.querySelector('#total-screen')



var checkboxesTotal = 0;
var selectTotal = 0;

checkboxes.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxSelect)
})

select.addEventListener('click', onSelectChange)

function onCheckboxSelect(e) {
  var sign = e.target.checked ? 1 : -1
  checkboxesTotal += sign * parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  
  const summary = getSummary(e.target);
  
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  // get selected value and assign it to the global variable selectTotal
  selectTotal = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  renderTotal();
  renderSummary(summary);
}

function onSelectChange(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    selectTotal = value
    renderTotal()
  }
}

function getSummary(selectedDiv) {
  const data = {totalScreen: +totalScreenDiv.innerText.replace(',',''), totalRange: +totalRangeDiv.innerText.replace(',', ''), totalOther: +totalOtherDiv.innerText.replace(',', '')};

  const sign = selectedDiv.checked ? 1 : -1;
  if(selectedDiv.getAttribute('id') === 'styled-checkbox-1') {
    if(sign === 1) {
      data.totalScreen += +(screen1.innerText.replace(',', ''));
      data.totalRange += +(range1.innerText.replace(',', ''));
      data.totalOther += +(other1.innerText.replace(',', ''));
    } else {
      if(data.totalScreen > 0) data.totalScreen -= +(screen2.innerText.replace(',', ''));
      if(data.totalRange > 0) data.totalRange -= +(range2.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      if(data.totalOther > 0) data.totalOther -= +(other3.innerText.replace(',', ''))
    }
  } else if(selectedDiv.getAttribute('id') === 'styled-checkbox-2') {
    if(sign === 1) {
      data.totalScreen += +(screen2.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      data.totalRange += +(range2.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      data.totalOther += +(other2.innerText.replace(',', ''))
    } else {
      if(data.totalScreen > 0) data.totalScreen -= +(screen2.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      if(data.totalRange > 0) data.totalRange -= +(range2.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      if(data.totalOther > 0) data.totalOther -= +(other2.innerText.replace(',', ''))
    }
  } else if(selectedDiv.getAttribute('id') === 'styled-checkbox-3') {
    if(sign === 1) {
      data.totalScreen += +(screen3.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      data.totalRange += +(range3.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      data.totalOther += +(other3.innerText.replace(',', ''))
    } else {
      if(data.totalScreen > 0) data.totalScreen -= +(screen3.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      if(data.totalRange > 0) data.totalRange -= +(range3.innerText.replace(',', ''))
      if(data.totalOther > 0) data.totalOther -= +(other3.innerText.replace(',', ''))
    }
  }
  
  return data;
}


function renderSummary({totalScreen, totalRange, totalOther}) {
  totalScreenDiv.innerHTML = totalScreen.toLocaleString();
  totalRangeDiv.innerHTML = totalRange.toLocaleString();
  totalOtherDiv.innerHTML = totalOther.toLocaleString();
}



function renderTotal() {
  //NORMALNA CENA
  total3.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal * selectTotal 
  // 10% TANIEJ
  total6.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-10) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)
  // 20% TANIEJ
  total12.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-20) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)

  //WADOWICE
}
```

```css
/*CENNIK*/
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Europa;
}
.pt_title {
    text-align: center;
    background: #2c4949;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.pt_months {
    color: #fff;
    background: #9B8C70;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
.col-x.month {
    text-align: center;
}
.cennik .pt-container {
    padding: 0 100px;
}
.col-x {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.pt_sub {
    background: #F4F1ED;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #00000029;
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;
}
.pt_sub .col-x {
    color: #352B25;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
/*TABLE*/
.cennik ul li {
    list-style: none!important;
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00000021;
    margin-left: 0!important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.cennik ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pt-place {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.pt-place .month {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2c4949;
}
.pt_table ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.pt-place .month span {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2c4949;
}
.pt_months .month {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
/*CHECKBOX*/
.checkbox.col-x {
    color: #858585;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.checkbox.col-x span:hover {
    color: #354949;
}
.styled-checkbox {
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0;
}
 .styled-checkbox + label {
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 0;
}
.styled-checkbox + label:before {
    content: '';
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: #ffffff00;
    border: 2px solid #858585;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.styled-checkbox:hover + label:before {
    background: #ffffff00;
    border: 4px solid #9B8C70;
}
 .styled-checkbox:focus + label:before {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.styled-checkbox:checked + label:before {
    background: #9B8C70;
}
 .styled-checkbox:disabled + label {
     color: #b8b8b8;
     cursor: auto;
}
 .styled-checkbox:disabled + label:before {
     box-shadow: none;
     background: #ddd;
}
.styled-checkbox:checked + label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 6.5px;
    top: 14px;
    background: #FDF1D1;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 0 #FDF1D1, 4px 0 0 #FDF1D1, 4px -2px 0 #FDF1D1, 4px -4px 0 #FDF1D1, 4px -6px 0 #FDF1D1, 4px -8px 0 #FDF1D1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.pt-place.disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
span.discount {
    color: #FFD383!important;
}
.cennik li.pt-place:hover {
    background: #f4f1ed;
}
.pt_footer {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FDF1D1;
    background: #2c4949;
    padding: 20px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.pt_footer span {
    color: #FDF1D1;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#payment-total,#payment-total2,#payment-total3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
.currency {
    color: #fff!important;
    text-transform: lowercase!important;
    font-size: 20px!important;
    letter-spacing: 0px!important;
}
.col-x.spot span {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.col-x.spot {
    margin-top: 5px;
}




.cennik select {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 16px;
}
.cennik select.round {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff00 50%, gray 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, grey 50%, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(#ddd0 70%, transparent 72%);
    background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 2px), calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px), calc(100% - .5em) .5em;
    background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1.5em 1.5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #2c4949;
}

.cennik select.round:focus {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #354949 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, #354949 50%), radial-gradient(#ff000000 70%, transparent 72%);
    background-position: calc(100% - 15px) 1em, calc(100% - 20px) 1em, calc(100% - .5em) .5em;
    background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1.5em 1.5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: 0;
}
.cennik .checkbox {
    margin-top: 0!important;
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
.cennik_page .wpb_raw_code.wpb_content_element.wpb_raw_html {
    margin-bottom: -10px!important;
}
span.link {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="cennik">
<div class="pt_header">
    <div class="pt_months">
        <div class="pt-container">
        <div class="col-x search" style="color: #0000;">Szukaj</div>
        <div class="col-x month">SCREENS</div>
        <div class="col-x month">RANGE</span></div>
        <div class="col-x month">OTHER</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pt_sub">
        <div class="pt-container">
        <div class="col-x">LOCATIONS:</div>
        <div class="col-x month">Digital Signage</div>
        <div class="col-x month">MONTHLY</div>
        <div class="col-x month">MONTHLY</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pt_table">
<ul>
<li class="pt-place">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="checkbox col-x"><input value="190" data-screen="5" type="checkbox" class="sum styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-1">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-1"><span class="link">PLACE ONE</span></label></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="screen-1">5</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="range-1">10,000</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="other-1">250,000</span></div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="pt-place">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="checkbox col-x"><input value="190" data-screen="6" type="checkbox" class="sum styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-2">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-2"><span class="link">PLACE TWO</span></label></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="screen-2">5</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="range-2">10,000</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="other-2">250,000</span></div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="pt-place">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="checkbox col-x"><input value="130" data-screen="4" type="checkbox" class="sum styled-checkbox" id="styled-checkbox-3">
    <label for="styled-checkbox-3"><span class="link">PLACE THREE</span></label></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="screen-3">5</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="range-3">10,000</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="other-3">250,000</span></div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="pt-place disabled">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="checkbox col-x"><span class="link">SUMMARY:</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="total-screen">0</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="total-range">0</span></div>
    <div class="col-x month"><span id="total-other">0</span></div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="pt_footer">
    <div class="pt-container">
    <div class="col-x spot">
    <span>Spot: </span>
    <select id="select" name="select" class="round">
        <option value="1" class="sum">5 seconds</option>
        <option value="2" class="sum" selected="selected">10 seconds</option>
        <option value="3" class="sum">15 seconds</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-x month"><span>3 MONTHS</span><hr style="border: none;
    margin: 4px;"><span id="payment-total">0</span> <span class="currency">$</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-x month"><span>6 MONTHS <span style="color:#FFD383">-10%</span></span><hr style="border: none;
    margin: 4px;"><span id="payment-total2">0</span> <span class="currency">$</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-x month"><span>12 MONTHS <span style="color:#FFD383">-20%</span></span><hr style="border: none;
    margin: 4px;"><span id="payment-total3">0</span> <span class="currency">$</span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Man, just wondering if it possible to add comma in the big numbers like  30,000?

Comment: @Lukas sure. I've edited my reply. I've just added `toLocaleString()` to the number to show like that

Comment: I tried this .toLocaleString('ES-es') but it shows the numer in such format only initially but when you choose checkboxes it shows NaN instead of numbers.

Comment: @Lukas thanks for mentioning me. Would you please create a new post describing your new issue you are facing and mention me there or share that post link with me. Since this solution is already getting larger.